# Disable Laravel Routing for a specific folder/route

Tags: php, laravel, web-development-server

I'm wondering how to disable the routing on laravel for a specific directory?

I am hoping to run my main website off of laravel (I'm rewriting it into the framework), but I'd like to retain my current forum software! The problem is, when  laravel sees the "localhost/forums" it looks for a forums controller or route. I'd like it to simply go to the literal /forums directory..?

Comment: Post your `routes.php` file

Comment: @Andreyco Could you help out?

Answer (score 15):

I had to add this line in public/.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foldername
```

before this line (that redirects trailing slashes)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Works like charm!! Thank you

Comment: This one works. Make sure you are updating .htaccess of the right directory

Answer (score 6):

With Laravel 4 none of these solutions were working for me. I eventually solved it by placing

```
RewriteRule ^(directory-name) - [L]
```

before

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

in public/.htaccess

Answer (score 4):

You need to make an exclusion in your `.htaccess` file. Just above the rule that sends everything to `index.php`, add this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums
```

Anything that begins with `/forums` will not be sent to Laravel.

(Of course, this is assuming you are using Apache.)

Comment: For me all the files in /public load normally without any changes to .htaccess. The problem is that something like /public/forum does not automatically load the index in that path anymore, it has to be accessed by /public/forum/index.php and the above rules does not help either. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

According to your `routes.php` file it is supposed to work.

1. You are not catching `forum` URL at all
2. If 'forum' directory/file exists, URL is not rewritten to Laravel's `index.php`

**`routes.php`** (I used this one in the test case)

```
Route::get('{slug}', function($slug){
    return $slug;
});
```

**File structure**

```
|- app
|- public
|--- index.php // Laravel's one
|--- forum // directory for forum files
|------ index.php // Forum's one
....
```

Using this structure, URL is not rewritten to Laravel's routing index.php file.
If I rename/remove `forum` folder URL is rewritten then.

Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to exclude /billing url on Laravel 5.7
So this way worked for me:

```
Route::redirect('/billing', '/billing');
```

when billing located at:
[My billing folder location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i977V.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using nginx, it's work for me:

```
location /your_folder {     
    try_files $uri $uri/ /your_folder/index.php?$args;
}
```