# Can I have Laravel control only certain folders?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am looked around and still can't figure it out.  I want laravel to only control certain folders of a website.  I have a new client where I plan to build out an admin section for them in an admin folder.  They will not setup a sub domain for the admin section.  I want to build this in Laravel 5.  The current site is a normal php with no framework or cms.  Then as a phase 2 I am going to be cleaning up their site and also will want to convert this over to laravel framework.  I am hoping their is a fairly straight forward way to do the admin section right away with Laravel and then go folder by folder and convert over their existing site.

Comment: They are called routes (not folders) and yes you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either handle this with your web server by not routing that URI to Laravel's index, or you can place files/folders inside the public folder of Laravel to be served like a regular flat-file PHP site.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18097472/1618438) too.

If you put your admin site in a folder inside of public called "admin", and made sure not to make any routes in laravel that used that "/admin" path, it should work just fine. Try it out!

Comment: Thanks I will have to test it out.  I don't have control over the environment as the site is on Rackspace Cloud Sites so the first option I think it out.  Second option seems just like what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

All Laravel routes (urls, folders, etc..) are defined in the app/Http/routes.php.

This means that only those routes will be available via your application. Here is a sample routes.php and let's assume that your domain name is example.com

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you will register all of the routes in an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {   // <--- This route is example.com
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/help', function(){ // <---- This route is example.com/help
   //logic
});


Route::get('/admin', function(){ // <--- This route is example.com/admin
   //logic
});
```

So you decide which links are available or not.