# Disable Laravel routing for another CMS in subfolder

Tags: laravel, redirect, nginx, centos7, octobercms

I'm using OctoberCMS (Laravel 5.1 LTS). I need to disable the Laravel routing overrides for subfolder: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmhW6.png).

---

`.htaccess` [file at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wbYsrST6) at line 9 i'm add the condition, but it doesnt work: HTTP ERROR 500.

I'm newbie, so it is difficult to deal with this on nginx. Thanks.

Comment: This would have to be done through the .htaccess file

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075290/disable-laravel-routing-for-a-specific-folder-route

Comment: @GONG, i know about this question, but its doesnt work for me, probably because i'm using nginx